# How to color table cell proportionally after adding an event ?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I implemented a table by creating linear layout for each column , and added buttons (by code) for each column as the number of cells in each column (same in all columns).
Now I have to color each cell after the user add an event , where each event's time can be in multiplies of 15 (e.g 12:15-13:00 , 12:45-13:15 etc...).

I tried to create shapes for quarter, half and full hour but i had bugs in adding two events in the same cell.

Are there any suggestions for implementing it as simple as possible ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In `Adapter` class, when you adding items to `TableLayout`, check event of the cell, and set background of `LinearLayout`-cell depending on event.

```
public enum Event{
    FIRST, SECOND
}

...

// in getView method in Adapter
switch(cell.event){
   case FIRST:
       linearLayoutCell.setBackogrundResource(FIRST_DRAWABLE_RESOURCE_ID);
       break;
   case SECOND:
       linearLayoutCell.setBackogrundResource(SECOND_DRAWABLE_RESOURCE_ID);
       break;    
}
```

Comment: The implementation should be with TableLayout and adapter for it ? What if there is an event in 12:00-12:15 and another one which is 12:45-13-15. the 12-13 cell should be colored twice.

Comment: depends. you mentioned "table". You can use TableLayout, GridLayout, other container, but the logic is one - filter your cell type and set corresponding backgrounds for cell parent layout or cell background itself.

Comment: Can you answer on the problem i'v noted in the comment above ? How would you solve it ?

Comment: can you provide UI screen with your TableLayout or schematic representation of the idea?

Comment: Here is a photo of the table i'v implemented .... [link]https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/395x600q90/661/72b874.png How do you color the same cell according to two different events ?

Comment: you will color cell according to more then 1 event? X events = X colors???? or what do you want to do? how many states has cell background?

Comment: Example: one event is from 11:00-12:30. second event is from 12:45-13:30. so, the cell 12-13 should be colored twice (same color).one from 12 to 12:30 and other from 12:45 to 13:00

Comment: Ok. I think that i figured it out. each cell is custom view that inherits Button or Textview and save in that class 4 booleans that mark the fill state of the current cell. Any feedback ?